# How to page through and preview recordings on Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of Recording (`List<Recording>`) objects:

```
Recording:
String title;
String length;
String long_text_about_the_recording;
String filepath; // /path/to/amr/file.amr
String other_meta_data;
```

To allow users to browse through this collections, I display these Recordings using a `PagedView`. The view that is being paged is a picture of a cassette tape on which the meta-data (title, length, etc) is displayed.

[image: Imgur]

That way, users can swipe through their collection. To make finding a specific Recording easier, I want to implement a preview/autoplayback mode accessed through a `Button`. So that when users press that button the current recording starts playing, but when they swipe to the next recording, the current recording stops playing and the next recording starts playing with as little delay as possible. What are the best strategies for implementing this without running into memory/file loading problems, also keeping in mind that users might swipe through their collections very quickly (i.e. skip over a recording) -- requiring some sort of threshold?